# VBA Array function returns error due to column formatting

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, formatting, copy-paste

I have created a database that takes a number of templates saved in a directory in csv format convert them to xlsx into a holding file then load into a log within another file.  Within that file is a summary database that holds unique records from the log and tracks a number of journeys.

The issue i face is once the data is copy pasted from the csvs to the log, the array function in the summary database doesn't pick up the date in column N in the log...I think this is a formatting issue but I don't know which part of my code holds the issue but the below is where the copy paste from the csvs to the log occurs how can i amend this so the array can read that there are dates in column N?

Basically i think this is another excel formatting issue i had recently where i had to click into each cell in order for the data to be read.

```
Public Sub LOAD_IT()
Dim strPath As String
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("template Log").Visible = True
    Set wb_main = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    wb_main.Worksheets("Summary Database").Unprotect Password:="########"
    wb_main.Worksheets("template Log").Unprotect Password:=" ########"
     
    'To UnHide Columns L
    Columns("L").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    Set ws_data = wb_main.Worksheets("Summary Database")
    Set ws_clog = wb_main.Worksheets("template Log")
    dat_eff = Now()

    ws_data.Activate
    ws_data.Cells(1, 1).Activate
    Set rg_data = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
    
    rg_data.Sort Key1:=Cells(1, TAD_NAPPY), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    
    ws_clog.Activate
    ws_clog.Cells(1, 1).Activate
    Set rg_clog = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
    
    csr_clog = rg_clog.Rows.Count + 1
    Set rg_clog = ws_clog.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(ws_clog.Rows.Count, rg_clog.Columns.Count))
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set fld_in = fso.GetFolder(STR_FLD_IN)
    
    fso.CopyFolder fld_in.Path, STR_FLD_BACKUP
    Set fld_backup = fso.GetFolder(STR_FLD_BACKUP & fld_in.Name & "\")
    fld_backup.Name = "inputs_" & Format(dat_eff, "ddmmyy hhmmss")

    If fld_in.Files.Count > 0 Then
        Set wb_in = Workbooks.Add
        Set ws_in = wb_in.Worksheets(1)

        For Each fil_in In fld_in.Files
            Call sub_get_inputload
        Next fil_in
        ws_in.Activate
        csr_in = ws_in.Cells(ws_in.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Do Until csr_in = 0
            If ws_in.Cells(csr_in, 1) = "" Then ws_in.Rows(csr_in).Delete
            csr_in = csr_in - 1
        
        Loop
        ws_in.Activate
        ws_in.Cells(1, 1).Activate
        Set rg_in = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
        Set rg_in = ws_in.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(rg_in.Rows.Count, IN_MAX))
        ws_in.Columns(1).NumberFormat = "00"
        ws_in.Columns(7).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        ws_in.Columns(13).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        Range("A1").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        
        For csr_data = 1 To rg_in.Rows.Count
            rg_in.Cells(csr_data, IN_NAPPY).Value = Trim(CStr(rg_in.Cells(csr_data, IN_NAPPY).Value))
        Next csr_data
        rg_in.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        ws_in.Cells(1, 1).Activate
        Set rg_in = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
        Set rg_in = ws_in.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(rg_in.Rows.Count, IN_MAX))

        rg_in.Sort Key1:=Cells(1, IN_NAPPY), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
     
        csr_data = 2
        For csr_in = 1 To rg_in.Rows.Count
        
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "\\xxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxx\HoldingFile.xlsx"
        Set wb_main1 = Workbooks("HoldingFile")
        
        On Error GoTo NothingCopied
        
        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks("Summary Database v2").Activate
        Sheets("template Log").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        With ActiveSheet
        Set rngCopy = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        Set rngPaste = .Range(.Range("A2"), _
             .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, rngCopy.Columns.Count)
        End With
        rngCopy.Copy
        'rngPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        rngPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Columns("B:B").Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
        Columns("N:N").Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        Columns("B:Z").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("$B:$Z").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=VBA.Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 _
        , 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25), _
        Header:=xlYes
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("template Log").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("template Log").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "N2:N1048576"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("template Log").Sort
        .SetRange Columns("B:AH")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Calculate
        
        On Error GoTo 0
        'Exit Sub

NothingCopied:
     'MsgBox "There is no data on the clipboard to be pasted."
     
 With Workbooks("HoldingFile")
 strPath = .FullName

 .Close savechanges:=False
 End With
 
 Kill strPath
  Exit For
  Next
      On Error Resume Next
    Kill "\\ xxxxxxxx \ xxxxxxxx \xxxxxxxx\Input Templates\*.csv*"
    On Error GoTo 0
  
  End If
  
   Application.Calculate
        Call Check_record_then_add_if_not_exist
        wb_main.Worksheets("Summary Database").Select
        
    Workbooks("Summary Database v2").Activate
    Sheets("template Log").Select
    Columns("N:N").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("N1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        
        Call ApplyFormulaetorows
        'Call Summary_Journey_PathsSendMail
        Application.Calculate
    For Each pc In Workbooks("Summary Database v2").PivotCaches
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    'pc.Refresh
  Next pc
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  
      'To Hide Columns L
    Sheets("Summary Database").Select
    Columns("L").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    
    wb_main.Worksheets("Summary Database").Protect Password:=" xxxxxxxx "
    wb_main.Worksheets("template Log").Protect Password:="sunshine"  
  Sheets("template Log").Visible = False
    MsgBox ("Upload into Database complete")
End Sub
```

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtHzT4JUElDdkhL_Bod8F8rHi55W?e=zZY7H9

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add some sample data and copy the complete code

Comment: @Ricardo Diaz the complete code is too long to send on here and includes sensitive references...how can i add the example data? sorry not too familiar,  can i send it to you privately?

Comment: @Ricardo Diaz added full code with some amendments to remove references

Comment: For the sample data you can upload a sample file in onedrive / googledrive and copy paste the link in your question

Comment: @Ricardo Diaz, sample data added with the array function in sheet tab #3

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question, but thought about giving you a hand so the process to find it it's easier.

Your code is difficult to follow the way it's structured.

Please check the following suggested code so you can refactor yours with some...

**Guidelines:**

- Add `Option explicit` to the top of your modules
- Name your variables to something meaningful (rg_data is hard to understand, dataRange it's easier)
- Indent your code properly (you can use Rubberduckvba.com) to help you with data
- Try to break your code into pieces (e.g. first validate, then prepare, then process files) you can use procedures to do this
- Comment your code

---

**Code:**
Option Explicit

```
' Remove this
Const TAD_NAPPY = "Something"
Const STR_FLD_IN = "Some folder name"
Const STR_FLD_BACKUP = "Some path"

Public Sub LoadDataFromLog()

    ' Set a reference to the complete workbook
    Dim mainWorkbook As Workbook
    Set mainWorkbook = Workbooks("HoldingFile")
    
    ' Set a reference to the summary database
    Dim summaryWorkbook As Workbook
    Set summaryWorkbook = Workbooks("Summary Database")
    
    ' Set a reference to the template log sheet
    Dim templateLogSheet As Worksheet
    Set templateLogSheet = summaryWorkbook.Worksheets("template Log")
    
    ' Set a reference to the summary sheet
    Dim summarySheet As Worksheet
    Set summarySheet = mainWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary Database")
    
    ' Prepare the main workbook
    PrepareMainWorkbook summarySheet, templateLogSheet
    
    ' Backup and process Files
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim folderIn As Object
    Set folderIn = fso.GetFolder(STR_FLD_IN)
    
    ' Backup files
    BackupFiles fso, folderIn

    ' Process files
    ProcessFiles folderIn
    
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessFiles(ByVal folderIn As Object)
    
    ' Validate if there are any files in folder
    If folderIn.Files.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Get input load
    Dim fileInFolder As Object
    For Each fileInFolder In folderIn.Files
        
        ' Call the sub (should pass the file as parameter?)
        sub_get_inputload
    
    Next fileInFolder
    
    ' Add workbook
    Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
    Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
    
    ' Get reference to new sheet
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Set newSheet = newWorkbook.Worksheets(1)


End Sub

Private Sub BackupFiles(ByVal fso As Object, folderIn As Object)
    
    fso.CopyFolder folderIn.Path, STR_FLD_BACKUP
    
    Dim folderBackup As Object
    Set folderBackup = fso.GetFolder(STR_FLD_BACKUP & folderIn.Name & "\")
    folderBackup.Name = "inputs_" & Format(Now(), "ddmmyy hhmmss")
    
End Sub

Private Sub PrepareMainWorkbook(ByVal summarySheet As Worksheet, ByVal templateLogSheet As Worksheet)

    ' Unprotect sheets
    summarySheet.Unprotect Password:="########"
    templateLogSheet.Unprotect Password:=" ########"
    
    ' Unhide column
    templateLogSheet.Columns("L").Hidden = False
    
    ' Sort summary database
    Dim summaryRange As Range
    Set summaryRange = summarySheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    summaryRange.Sort Key1:=Cells(1, TAD_NAPPY), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that and noted will adopt for future workings.  any suggestion how can i get the array to read a copy pasted field / get the holding file to paste in in a readable format?

Comment: The N column is holding the dates but when you put them in an array, dates in Excel are stored as numbers.